# Execute a function only if the window is wider than 1024px, check the width in real time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a page that allows you to scroll by sections. Each section has the height of the window. My inspiration is the [tesla.com](https://tesla.com) website. The problem is when you resize the page so its width is less than 1024px, the overflow-y is shown (for mobile devices) and it makes the navigation jumpy, so i want the function to work only  when the window is wider than 1024px. I have figured out how to do so when the page loads, but I have no idea how to do so when someone resizes the page.The width of the window has to be in real time, right now it only retrieves the width once, after the page loads.

My HTML:

```
   <body>
    <div class="slide first">
        <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide second">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide third">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide forth">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

My javaScript:

```
history.scrollRestoration = "manual";

if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) {
  window.onload = sectionScrolling;
}

function sectionScrolling() {
  const firstSlide = document.querySelector(".first");
  const secondSlide = document.querySelector(".second");
  const thirdSlide = document.querySelector(".third");
  const forthdSlide = document.querySelector(".forth");
  const slides = [firstSlide, secondSlide, thirdSlide, forthdSlide];
  let scrollCount = 0;

  function slider(event) {
    if (event.deltaY < 0 && scrollCount > 0) {
      scrollCount--;
    } else if (event.deltaY > 0 && scrollCount < 3) {
      scrollCount++;
    }
    console.log(slides[scrollCount]);
    slides[scrollCount].scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
  }

  let enableCall = true;
  window.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    if (!enableCall) return;
    enableCall = false;
    slider(event);
    setTimeout(function() {
      enableCall = true;
    }, 400);
  });
}
```

Here is the Codepen. Thank you in advance.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nazar-klymenko/full/XWWdKqZ

Comment: Thank you, i know about the resize event, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it in my code. When i add ```window.onresize = getWidth;``` i cannot retrieve the value from the function because it is not globally scoped, and if i wrap my code inside the ```getWidth``` function it calls my code every time i resize, making it fire multiple times.

Comment: I believe you can simply check the condition inside `slider()` or the wheel listener

Comment: Btw, I don't think resize page while use is something easy to happen on normal client, especially mobile.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I have added an ```if``` statement after the ```wheel``` event listener, so now it checks the condition every time the ```wheel``` event is triggered. The problem i have had was with someone resizing the browser. If the browser window would have been small it would trigger the css media query which was intended for the mobile devices. The function and the css style that the media query sets did not work together well.